# Unit Testing Delete, record returned even though it is deleted in the DB

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, nunit

I am using Nunit to test a method in my controller which deletes a record from the DB.  Everything works correctly and the record is deleted when I check but somehow

```
db.AssesorMaxProjectLoad.Find(previousLoad.ID)
```

still returns the deleted value and makes my test fail.

Test:

```
[Test]
public void AssesorMaxProjectLoadsDeleteLoad()
{
   var previousLoad = db.AssesorMaxProjectLoad.Where(t => t.AssesorID == testAssesor3ID).FirstOrDefault(t => t.TaskGroupID == taskGroupID);
   var result = controller.DeleteConfirmed(previousLoad.ID) as ViewResultBase;
   var newProjectLoad = db.AssesorMaxProjectLoad.Find(previousLoad.ID).MaxAssignedProjectLoad;
   Assert.AreEqual(null, newProjectLoad);
}
```

Controller Method its Testing:

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
{
   AssesorMaxProjectLoad assesorMaxProjectLoad = db.AssesorMaxProjectLoad.Find(id);
   db.AssesorMaxProjectLoad.Remove(assesorMaxProjectLoad);
   db.SaveChanges();
   return RedirectToAction("Index", "AssesorMaxProjectLoads", new { id = assesorMaxProjectLoad.TaskGroupID });
}
```

Whats going on or what am I missing? I don't understand how it can be returned when it is no longer in the database?

Comment: Where does db comes from in your test ? Is it possible that its a different context instance and that it has the entity cached ?

Comment: Is this an integration test?

Comment: Yes it is indeed an integration test

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because the `DbContext` in your unit test is disconnected from the `DbContext` in your controller method.

What's happening if you have two instances of `DbContext`. When you delete a record in the database, that change is not promulgated to the other context and so when you do a find for your record, the unit test context doesn't know anything has changed and returns the original value.

You will need to recreate the `DbContext` in your unit test *after* you run the controller method to ensure you are looking at the latest data.

Alternatively, look into mocking the `DbContext` calls entirely.

Comment: So simple how could I have missed it, that is exactly the problem.  Thank you very much

Comment: @Steve - Well-spotted, +1.

Comment: @Brian oh believe me, it's a hard earned knowledge that one.